# Can there be generator getters in classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I mean getters that are generators. All this is ES6+ I believe. Like this maybe.

```
class a {
    get *count() {
        let i = 10;
        while(--i) yield i;
    }
}

let b = new a;
for(const i of b.count)
    console.log(i);
```

That doesn't work through, I am placing the asterisk wrong (that is if this is possible at all)

> unexpected identifier *

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no shorthand notation for this. You can however return a generator from a getter property without any difference:

```
function* countdown(i) {
    while(--i) yield i;
}
class a {
    get count() {
        return countdown(10);
    }
}
```

I would recommend to avoid this though. Getters that return distinct stateful objects on consecutive calls can be quite confusing.

Answer (score -2):

Another example of something you shouldn't do, but effectively this is a generator on a getter without using the generator function syntax.

```js
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.18.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> class Counter {
... constructor() {
...   this._reqId = 1
... }
... set reqId(newReqId) {
...   this._reqId = newReqId
... }
... get reqId() {
...   return this._reqId++
... }
... }
undefined
> const c = new Counter()
undefined
> c.reqId
1
> c.reqId
2
> c.reqId
3
> c.reqId
4
> c.reqId
5
> c.reqId
6
```