# Syntax for iterable getter?

Tags: typescript, generator, getter

Can I declare getter, who behaves like function generator?

My attempts

```
class Foo {
    * Test1(): IterableIterator<string> { // Works, but not a getter...
        yield "Hello!"; 
    }

    * get Test2(): IterableIterator<string> { // Syntax error
        yield "Hello!"; 
    }

    get * Test3(): IterableIterator<string> { // Syntax error
        yield "Hello!"; 
    }

    get Test4(): IterableIterator<string> { // Works, but ugly syntax...
        return function* (): IterableIterator<string> {
            yield "Hello!";
        }();
    }
}
```

For example in C#, this is perfectly valid...

```
class Foo
{
    IEnumerable<string> Test
    {
        get
        {
            yield return "Hello!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write the errors you get, they are likely to be highly relevant. As far as I know, the `*`-notation is only available after the keyword `function`.

Comment: I think the ugly but work solution is the only ne taht will work

Comment: @AJFarmar This is valid syntax in class. See [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%20Test()%3A%20IterableIterator%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20%22Hello!%22%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(foo.Test().next().value)%3B).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004308/2407212

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such syntax in TypeScript or JavaScript. A getter should return an iterator:

```
class Foo {
    private * _bar() {
        yield "Hello!"; 
    }

    get bar(): IterableIterator<string> {
        return this._bar();
    }
}
```

This can be addressed with a decorator, but since class mutation isn't well supported in decorators, proper typing should be handled manually:

```
function get<T>(getter: keyof T) {
    return (target: any, method: string, descriptor?: any) => {
        Object.defineProperty(target, getter, {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: false,
            get() {
                return this[method]();
            }
        });
    }; 
}

interface Foo {
    bar: IterableIterator<string>;
}
class Foo {
    @get<Foo>('bar')
    private * _bar() {
        yield "Hello!"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this trick if you don't want to create private generator method:

```
class WithIterableGetter {
  a: string
  b: string
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'abc'
    this.b = 'bcd'
  }

  get getter(): IterableIterator<string> {
    let i = 0;
    let self = this;
    return {
      next: function() {
        return {
          done: i > 1,
          value: self[i++ === 0 ? 'a' : 'b']
        };
      },
      [Symbol.iterator]: function() { return this; }
    }
  }
}

for (const i of new WithIterableGetter().getter) {
  console.log(i)
}
```